# Understanding a topological proof involoving set theory

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

Here is the proof of the following statement: "Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function with $X$ and $Y$ topological spaces. If f is continuous, then for all $F \subset Y$ closed, $f^{-1}(F) \subset X$ is closed.

I will write the whole proof but only the last line is troubling me:

Let $F = Y \setminus U , U \subset Y$ open

$U = Y \setminus F$

$f^{-1}(Y\setminus F) \subset X$ is open

$= f^{-1}(Y)\setminus f^{-1}(F)$ is open

$\implies X\setminus (f^{-1}(Y) \setminus f^{-1}(F)) $ is closed in $X$

$\implies f^{-1}(F)$ is closed   $(*)$

The I don't understand the last line $(*)$

Comment: The last line is wrong (I suggested an edit). Also note that $f^{-1}(Y)=X$.

Comment: The last lines are puzzling. At "$f^{-1}(Y) \setminus f^{-1}(F)$ is open", the natural thing is to use $f^{-1}(Y) = X$, which gives $X\setminus f^{-1}(F)$ is open, and then $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed. We can write $f^{-1}(F)$ as $X \setminus (X\setminus f^{-1}(F))$, so the penultimate line is not wrong (just strange). The last line is true, since $f^{-1}(F)\setminus X = \varnothing$, but doesn't imply the assertion.

Comment: @Simon Is$ f^{-1}(Y)=X$ because f is continuous?

Comment: No, that's because $f$ is a map with domain $X$ and codomain $Y$. So every $x \in X$ is mapped to $Y$, and $f^{-1}(Y) = \{ x \in X : f(x) \in Y\} = X$.

Comment: No. That is true for any function. The preimage of the whole set Y is the whole set X.

Comment: Thank you, I understood now !